# odoo when create product I got Record does not exist or has been deleted. (Record: account.account(5913,), User: 104)

Tags: odoo, product

In Odoo 13 when I try to create product from sale or from inventory, I got this message:

```
Record does not exist or has been deleted. (Record: account.account(5913,), User: 104)
```

will you please help or advice how to fix this

Comment: Can you share more details like what are the steps and which custom module have been installed which will affecting this?

Comment: no any custom module - I think I delete one journal that the reason -but is odoo week like this? and no soluation

Answer (score 0):

The current user **may not have access rights** to the record you are trying to access, in **Odoo** when you call any function it **automatically gets the current logged-in user's access rights**.

To access the record, you may need to use:

```
sudo()
```

It gives you the access rights of the **superuser** (access to all records), but then again it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, meaning you're gonna need to give the user **the proper access rights** to the file or use the superuser in the python function.